# nextSibling doesn't work when working with PHP DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I tried to get a following element using `nextSibling` and the following code doesn't work.
i've got an error as below
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /php/dom.php on line 35

that must be caused by the null value in the foreach loop.

but if I modify it to get the previous element using `previousSibling` it works as expected.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$html = <<<HTML
<html>
<body>
<ul id="list">
<li>Foo</li>
<li>Bar</li>
</ul>
<h2 class = 'test'>heading2</h2>
<ul id="list2">
<li>list1</li>
<li>list2</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
HTML;

$doc ->loadHTML($html);

$DOMNodelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');

foreach($DOMNodelist as $node) {
    if ($node -> hasAttribute('class')) {    
        foreach($node -> nextSibling ->childNodes as $morenodes) {
           print_r($morenodes);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify "doesn't work" -- do you get an error, nothing prints, etc.

Comment: updated it. got:PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /php/dom.php on line 35

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your document has whitespace separating the elements, you'd actually need to use:
`nextSibling->nextSibling`
Or, the way I'd do it, because you already have a list generated from `'*'` for all the elements, I'd write it as:

```
foreach($DOMNodelist as $i=>$node) {
    if ($node -> hasAttribute('class')) {
        foreach($DOMNodelist->item($i+1)->childNodes as $morenodes) {
           print_r($morenodes);
       }
    }
}
```

Or you can just remove the whitespace from the document:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<html><body><ul id="list"><li>Foo</li><li>Bar</li></ul><h2 class = 'test'>heading3</h2><h3>heading3</h3><ul id="list2"><li>list2</li><li>list2</li></ul></body></html>
HTML;
```

Comment: both of your examples work. but i'm not sure if it is caused by whitespace. i set the preserveWhiteSpace to false and that makes no difference. According to http://cn2.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.preservewhitespace, whitespace will be removed if you set it to false. please do correct me if i got it all wrong. Thank you

Comment: `$doc->preserveWhiteSpace=false;` would work too but only if you use `$doc->loadXML($html);` rather than `$doc->loadHTML($html);` as it's an XML feature only.

Comment: nextSibling -> nextSibling works. does that mean the white space between them is treated as an element?

Comment: According to the DOM's terminology based on the createTextNode method, the whitespace is called a "node", while actual elements, created by createElement, are known as elements although they also count as nodes. previous and nextSibling allow you to browse through the nodes rather than the elements. childNodes gives you access to nodes rather than elements. But getElementsByTagName gives you access to actual elements.

Comment: i've just tried $doc -> loadXML($html) and set preserveWhiteSpace to false, and nextSibling still doesn't work. i guess this simply doesn't work with loading html file? Thanks your patience.

Comment: [this](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/32x-sbk) works for me as seen [here](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/32x-sbk)

Comment: my bad, i put preserveWhiteSpace after loading the html. Now the problem is solved.Thank you again

Answer (score 4):

The next sibling is actually a text node which doesn't have any child nodes to iterate; you can use this helper function to get the next sibling element instead:

```
function nextElementSibling($node)
{
    while ($node && ($node = $node->nextSibling)) {
        if ($node instanceof DOMElement) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return $node;
}

if ($node->hasAttribute('class')) {
    foreach(nextElementSibling($node)->childNodes as $morenodes) {
       print_r($morenodes);
   }
}
```

Comment: i removed the h3 tag and tried to get ul elements but it remains the same result.

Comment: @benson What exactly do you mean by the same result? It works just fine [in this codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GzAAdl).